# how to find the longest path of increasing numbers in a grid?

Tags: algorithm

Assuming we have a grid:

```
1 5 7
3 4 9
6 2 8
```

The solution would be: 1-3-4-5-7-9

How would this be solved?

Comment: Where is your attempt at an answer?

Answer (score 6):

I think this problem can be solved using recursive dp. Just memoise the lenght of the longest path obtained by starting at a particular point.

```
int dp[rows][cols]={0};
int dfs(int x , int y , int val)
    {
       if(dp[i][j] != 0 ) // already visited
        return dp[i][j];
       int lengthoflongestpath = 0;
       Search in four directions in the grid for the element greater than val; // Say newx, newy,newval
       lengthoflongestpath = max(lengthoflongestpath , dfs( newx , newy , newval));
       lengthoflongestpath ++; // add that particular element to the path
       dp[x][y] = lengthoflongestpath;
       return dp[x][y];
    }


int ans = 0;   
for(i=0 to rows)
 for(j=0 to cols)
   if(dp[i][j] == 0) // unvisited
    {
     dp[i][j] = dfs(i,j,grid[i][j]);
     ans = max(ans,dp[i][j]);
    }
 PRINT ans;
```

This returns the length of the longest path. For printing the exact path we need to use a NEXT ARRAY and store the next element which returns the maximum "lenghtofthelongestpath" accordingly.

Complexity : Rows * Cols

Edit : How to search in 4 directions.

```
int dx[] = {1,-1,0,0};
int dy[] = {0,0,1,-1};

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
 {
      int newx = x + dx[i];
      int newy = y + dy[i];
      if(newx and newy lie inside the grid and newval > val)
        dfs(newx,newy,newval);
 }
```

Comment: will work like a charm!

Comment: could you clarify how I would do the "Search in four directions in the grid for the element greater than val"?

Comment: Added that part.
Search in 4 directions means search the surrounding neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds trivial if you use recursively and your grid data structure includes a flag that tells you whether you've used a number or not.

```
List explore(Point start, Grid grid) {
    List result = {}
    for Point next in possible_choices(start, grid) {
        grid.markUsed(next)
        List proposed = explore(next, grid)
        if(proposed.length > result.length) result = proposed;
        else grid.markNotUsed(next)           
    }
    result.prepend(start)

    return result
}
```

I didn't spend too much time on the algorithm but it'd be something along those lines...